# Webview change depending on the version of Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

with the introduction of Android 4.4 has changed the webview, I would understand that if the app is running on Android 4.4 with this type of webview:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings (); 
settings.setUseWideViewPort (true); 
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode (true);
```

otherwise it executes the code that I already have that with the webview on Android versions less than 4.4 works great. you can do an if?

Comment: I would like someone to help me create the "if"

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) { 
    // do stuff for older than Kitkat.
}
```

Comment: I already have a webview that works well for me and less than 4.3, the if I want to do just to kitkat performing this part here http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html

Answer (score 0):

Get the device's OS version with [android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT), and the compare it with the kitkat version code. [Build.VERSION_CODES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings (); 
    settings.setUseWideViewPort (true); 
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode (true);

    doMoreKitKatStuff();
}
```